# Extracting the first Just value from [Maybe a]

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

Say I have a list like:

```
[Nothing, Just 1, Nothing, Just 2]
```

I want to get the first `Just` (non-error) value; in this case, it's `Just 1`. The only thing I can think of is:

```
firstJust xs = case filter isJust xs of
                 []     -> Nothing
                 Just x -> Just x
```

Is there a better/monad-generic way to do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[**`msum`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:msum) from `Control.Monad`:

```
\> msum [Nothing, Just 1, Nothing, Just 2]
Just 1
```

or [**`asum`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:asum) from `Data.Foldable`:

```
\> asum [Nothing, Just 1, Nothing, Just 2]
Just 1
```

Both are documented as:

> The sum of a collection of actions, generalizing `concat`.

with signature:

```
msum :: (Foldable t, MonadPlus m) => t (m a) -> m a
asum :: (Foldable t, Alternative f) => t (f a) -> f a
```

and behave as above due to [`Maybe` instance of `Alternative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-685).

Comment: By switching from `Maybe` to `First`, you can just use `fold`.

Comment: Seems to need `firstJust xs = asum xs <|> Nothing` to handle empty lists.

Comment: @StevenShaw `asum ([] :: [Maybe Int])` is `Nothing` so no problem with empty lists.

Comment: @dfeuer This has the advantage that you could use `Last` with the same approach.

Answer (score 4):

```
import Data.Foldable (find)
import Data.Maybe (isJust)
import Control.Monad (join)

firstJust = join . find isJust
```

Usage:

```
> firstJust [Nothing, Just 1, Nothing, Just 2]
Just 1

> firstJust [Nothing, Nothing]
Nothing
```